# With Microsoft OpenSSH server for Windows, how do we quote space characters in forced commands in the authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2019

We have setup **Microsoft's implementation of OpenSSH server** on a Windows server 2019 (v1809) and have activated authentication based on public keys. We would like to deploy **forced commands** and are struggling with **space characters in the path** of such commands.

A minimal example:

User `user1` has the following `authorized_keys` file:

```
command="C:\Program Files\SomePath\SomeProgram.exe" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3N...
```

When we try to `ssh` into that machine as that user, the following happens:

```
$ ssh -i <user1_key_id> user1@server.example.com

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Connection to server.example.com closed.
```

(Please note that we have an SSH agent running so that there is no passphrase query in the above terminal session snippet.)

IMHO, it's quite clear that the problem is due to the space character in the path of the program which should be executed. However, we are unsure why the double quotes around the command in the `authorized_keys` file don't prevent the problem. We have tried to add a further pair of double quotes using the well-known escaping methods:

```
command="\"C:\Program Files\SomePath\SomeProgram.exe\"" ...

command="^"C:\Program Files\SomePath\SomeProgram.exe^"" ...
command="""C:\Program Files\SomePath\SomeProgram.exe""" ...
```

The first one lead to the same error as described above. The second one and the third one lead to another error message:

```
user1@server.example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Now we are stuck and have the following question:

How do we need to write the command above in the `authorized_key` files for Microsoft OpenSSH server for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The command to be executed is the whole line after the "command=" moniker.

Quotes are required to protect the spaces in your executable's path on the target server.
Quotes in the authorized_keys file need to be escaped with *backslashes*:

So, it should look something like this:

```
command=\"C:\Program Files\SomePath\SomeProgram.exe\" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3N...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. However, this leads to the `permission denied` error described in my original post ...